# How do I duplicate documents (with some changes) in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I have some documents

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("1"),
  "name": "dean",
  "version": 1
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("2"),
  "name": "john",
  "version": 1
}
```

I want to duplicate the contents of these documents, setting `version` to `2` in the copies.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("1"),
  "name": "dean",
  "version": 1
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("2"),
  "name": "john",
  "version": 1
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("3"),
  "name": "dean",
  "version": 2
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("4"),
  "name": "john",
  "version": 2
}
```

I'll then make whatever changes I want for version 2.

How do I go about making these copies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out a way:

```
db.collection.find({version: 1}).forEach(function(doc) {
  doc._id = ObjectId();
  doc.version = 2;  
  db.collection.insert(doc);
});
```